Sign-in Failed Your Apple ID does not support the expected services on this device
I followed all the steps mentioned in Link and also watched the Apple developer video to understand the required JSON structure.
Problem: However, I am still encountering the error "Sign-in Failed: Your Apple ID does not support the expected services on this device" while trying to sign in to a work or school account from my personal iPhone to test Apple account driven user enrollment.
Cross Checked:

I ensured the domain name used is federated in Apple Business
Manager, and accounts with this domain name can sign in to ABM as
staff. Although ABM does not allow initial sign-in, it does
recognize the account.
I am using Microsoft Intune to enroll any iOS device to access
company resources and have followed MS recommendation mentioned in
thislink


Currently, the device is not enrolled. When I attempt to enroll, I
expect to see a log on the server side where the well-known file is
hosted, but there is no trace of it. However, when I manually access
the well-known endpoint via a browser or using curl, I receive an
HTTP 200 response, and the content-type shows 'application/json',
which confirms the server is responding properly.
curl -I https://contoso.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement.json


This is the response I get when I ran the above command from Terminal
"HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/json
content-length: 172
date: Mon, 29 Apr 2024 09:18:21 GMT"
So, as you can above I have examined the well-known file hosted, seems to be responding as expected, and I think the issue lies on something is not correct while Apple tries to access this well-known endpoint and I have no clue at this point. Therefore, if you have faced the same issue in the past and solved it please shed some light here.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit this to state a clear goal? What one device or link is not letting you log in here? Have you passed a payload to that device? Is it enrolled, pre enrollment or unmanaged?

What is the curl command you are using to test your exact MDM? What are the return status? When you say you followed all the steps in n8’s post there are very many and you need to fill in some blanks, it’s not complete for any specific MDM so it’s general

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I finally figured out the problem, and I didn't think it would be that simple. I hosted the file with a .json extension, and after removing it, everything started working for me.

Yes, I just removed the extension from the URL path, it used to be like this "https://contoso.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement.json" then I changed it to "https://contoso.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement"

we also need to make sure curl -I "contoso.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement" it should return HTTP 200 + returns the JSON as response. hope this information helps

Looks like Apple had a hiccup and had to do maintenance on the servers on the back end. Your error message and timing correspond with many other people getting authentication errors with developer associated Apple ID.

https://daringfireball.net/linked/2024/04/27/apple-id-lockout
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/


I would reach out to Apple support or developer support if you continue to have issues after I post this answer.

I just did a fiddler trace on my iOS device and I found that it returns HTTP 404 status code while performing a GET call to the following endpoint and it looks for user identifier. bold https://contoso.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement.json?user-identifier=abcuser@contoso.com&model-family=iPhone. The well-know file which I have hosted cannot return user-identifier as a response, as it meant to return only tenant information as mentioned in the Microsoft [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/apple-account-driven-user-enrollment)

Nice. You have personalized values and not just controls.com, correct?
